# Install conda package inside IPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I can install pip packages inside IPython by writing `!pip install name`. I am however unable to do this with conda. The following example just gets stuck when executed in Jupyter Notebook `!conda install -c anaconda pillow -y`.

Anyone who can explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good post found here : https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

It talks about issues using conda within notebooks and suggests

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} <package>
```

It will go into further detail down the blog post to explain why it gets messy due to system path variables if you really want to get into it.